# ErrorListPlot fails to display error bars

Tags: plotting, bugs

ErrorListPlot fails to display error bars for me, for example with the Example in Help

```
ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]]
```

returns

[image]

My Mathematica (11.2.0.0 on Mac Sierra) set up automatically starts with

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
```

and also starts with (among other things)

```
SetOptions[ListLogPlot,       Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Automatic,15], Axes -> False, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Palatino", 15}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black,20,Thickness->0.0025], FrameTicksStyle -> Plain, ImageSize -> 500, ImageMargins -> 10, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}];
```

Could it be that ErrorListPlot calls ListPlot and is incompatible with Frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: This is a known incompatibility between `ErrorListPlot` and `PlotMarkers` and there is a fix in an upcoming release. There is a workaround, though.

This is too long for a comment. When diagnosing an issue, an attempt should be made to break this down into a minimal example. First, I would ensure that it works without the additional options present, i.e. temporarily disable your `init.m` file.

```
ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]]
```

[image]

Second, test if `ErrorListPlot` is effected by setting the options on `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{ListPlot},
 SetOptions[ListPlot, Frame -> True];
 ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]]
]
```

[image]

which appears it does. But, as you can see it's not the `Frame`. So, we need to work through what option actually does it. I like `Association` for this, and it is simpler if we run this against `ErrorListPlot` directly:

```
Association[
 First[#] -> ErrorListPlot[
     Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}], #] & /@
  {Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Automatic, 15], Axes -> False, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Palatino", 15}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 20, Thickness -> 0.0025], 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Plain, ImageSize -> 500, ImageMargins -> 10, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}}]
```

I'm not going to include the output of the whole thing here as the issue is `PlotMarkers`.

```
ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}]
```

[image]

`PlotMarkers` is implemented by using `GeometricTransformation` which describes how to position the markers using only a single copy of the plot marker. It is a space saving device.

```
In[21]:= Cases[ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}], 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}], _GeometricTransformation, -1]

(*Out[21]=
{GeometricTransformation[{Inset[Style["\[FilledCircle]", FontSize -> 15], {0., 0.}], {}}, 
{{{1., 1.}}, {{2., 2.}}, {{3., 3.}}, {{4., 4.}}, {{5., 5.}}, {{6., 6.}}, {{7., 7.}}, 
{{8., 8.}}, {{9., 9.}}, {{10., 10.}}}]}*)
```

At issue is that `ErrorListPlot` does not know how to work with `GeometricTransformation`. Also, there is not a simple way to patch the issue short of modifying the package directly, partially because `Normal` does not expand `GeometricTransformation` (another known issue). The issue with `ErrorListPlot` is being addressed in an upcoming release.

In the meantime, a workaround is to lay one plot on top of the other to "simulate" the effect, e.g.

```
With[{data = Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]},
 Show[ErrorListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}],
  ErrorListPlot[data]]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks collyre. I like your workaround solution which is very simple.